# Access Member already exists in an object module

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have created a form and it works fine. Then I want to copy this form in the same database. 
Then I got this error.

> Member already exists in an object module from which this object
>   module derives

I have a Form_Load() in my original form and if I comment this sub-procedure in my copied form, it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: @krish that doesn't answer my question. I am sure I don't have same control name and procedure name (ie. I don't have a control name "Load")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

( very wild guess ) Eyeball the forms VBA code in the global declaration section (up top) and make sure there are no .dll calls, enumerations, global variables, etc. whose scope is the entire database, and are now declared twice with a form copy-paste.

Comment: brilliant!!! I thought the "global" variables were only within its module. but is there any way to declare a variable with scope only within its module?

Comment: Just don't use the keyword public or global instead dim in your form module.

Comment: Yes, declare it private (essentially same as above comment.

Comment: Also most developers I know will have a single module, called something like modGlobals, specifically for all public/global variables.

Comment: THIS!!!!!! At some point in time (years ago), something must have changed in MS access VBA, and duplicate subs in different modules would cause "member already exists".  But this error doesn't get triggered when you use the sub in question, but when you try any other method call (i.e. Me.Parent).  So then you get this nonsensical error on "Me.Parent" and are going insane.   VBA is not fun.